# Communicate with USB device on Android

Tags: java, android, usb

I have an RFID usb reader for Windows which acts as an external keyboard. When plugged into my laptop the reader transmits a number (0014671609) when an RFID object is scanned (like you would type in the number on a real keyboard).

My goal is to make an Android app which also prints the number when a RFID object is scanned.

Currently, I can connect to the device and when I scan something I get a response, but I have trouble reading the response. Here is my code:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        int packetSize = deviceEndpoint.getMaxPacketSize();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(packetSize);

        UsbRequest outRequest = new UsbRequest();
        outRequest.initialize(deviceConnection, deviceEndpoint);
        outRequest.queue(buffer, 1);

        if (deviceConnection.requestWait() == outRequest) {

            UsbRequest inRequest = new UsbRequest();
            inRequest.initialize(deviceConnection, deviceEndpoint);

            if(inRequest.queue(buffer, packetSize) == true){

                deviceConnection.requestWait();

                // get response data
                byte[] data = buffer.array();
                System.out.println("Response: " + new String(data, "UTF-8"));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage().toString());
    }
}
```

The reponse:

```
Response: ����'����������
```

Comment: Are you sure the RFID reader uses UTF-8 encoding? It looks like that's the encoding you're trying to decode the bytes with, however in my experience the diamonds with question marks mean you're using the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in android you can use the dispatchKeyEvent in your main activity.
I have a similar setup except with a barcode scanner which transmits a barcode as if i would enter it with an external keyboard.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    System.out.println(event.getAction() + " " + event.getKeyCode() + " - " + (char) event.getUnicodeChar());

    return true;
}
```

this should help you if you want to get the information. you should only know when the RFID sequence finished. does it transmit a suffix which you can look out for?

remember that this method catches all key events: key up as well as key down. you should filter for this.

Comment: Jup, it looks like it does. Thank you so much! I did not know it was this simple.. I'll accept your answer when I'm allowed.